# Passing JS var into the Selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a trouble with following Javascript function.

there are many divs with ID conversation and specific numbers, like this div id="conversation-123" for example.

I need to target the specific form elements inside of every div with conversation ID.

I tried a lot of different code, this is where Im stuck now.

```
var unid = 'conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?>';
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
  validate();
  $('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?> #realname').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
  var unid = 'conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?>';
  console.log(unid);
  if (jQuery("#" + unid + " #realname").val().length    >   0) {
    jQuery("#" + unid + " button#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    jQuery("#" + unid + " button#submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

This is what I see in when I view page source:

```
var unid = 'conversation-250';
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
  validate();
  var unid = 'conversation-250'
  $("#" + unid + "#realname").change(validate);
});

function validate(){
  var unid = 'conversation-250';
  console.log(unid);
  if (jQuery("#" + unid + "#realname").val().length    >   0) {
    jQuery("#" + unid + "button#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    jQuery("#" + unid + "button#submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

as you can see, var unid = 'conversation-250'; was converted properly to the number specific to div, but inside the selector function, instead of conversation-250 I have "unid", so it didnt convert to value. It just printed the variable name.

Console in firebug shows this:

```
conversation-213 (this is comming from console.log)
TypeError: jQuery(...).val(...) is undefined
```

Im stuck on this issue for half a day already... Browsed through a lot of tutorials and solutions but none worked for me. Please help :)

Thank you

EDIT:

You guys indicated that repeating IDs might be the problem, even if I target these repeating IDs through their parent unique ID divs..

I updated the code and now each of these IDs have same dynamically generated number.

for example, before it was #realname, now it is #realname-270

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
      validate();
      $('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?> input#realname-<?php the_ID(); ?>').change(validate);
    });

    function validate(){
      if (jQuery('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?> input#realname-<?php the_ID(); ?>').val().length > 0) {
          //-----------
        jQuery('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?> button#submit-<?php the_ID(); ?>').prop("disabled", true);
      }
      else {
        jQuery('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?> button#submit-<?php the_ID(); ?>').prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
```

when I view source now, I do see correct IDs generated, however, the code doesnt work, and in console I still see following error message:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).val(...) is undefined
```

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique with the document. The fact that you've got a uniquely generated ID (`#conversation-250`) which contains a generic probably not-unique ID (`#realname`) is potentially a problem.

Comment: Thanks for response. I edited the code but still have the "TypeError: jQuery(...).val(...) is undefined" error. View the question please, updates are below line "EDIT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give some space:

```
if (jQuery("#" + unid + " #realname").val().length > 0) {
//----------------------^
```

**Code:**

```
function validate() {
    var unid = 'conversation-250';
    console.log(unid);
    if (jQuery("#" + unid + " #realname").val().length > 0) {
        jQuery("#" + unid + " button#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#" + unid + " button#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

And I feel like you are duplicating these `id`s, which is wrong too:

- `#realname`
- `button#submit`

Comment: hi Praveen, thanks for the response. I added the comment / empty line below that line as you said, but result is still the same. 
as for duplicate IDs, I dont understand what you mean its an if condition, if the value is more than 0 in the input field #realname, then make #conversation-250 button#submit disabled...

Comment: Thats what Im trying to achieve, considering that there will be many same ID buttons on the page, since page will have multiple of the same form with same ID on button, thats why Im trying to target the buttons like that, target through parent div, which have unique number after 'conversation-"

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: Well, class wont really help in this case... script should disable the submit button if the value of the field is more than 0... Now problem is that, if it disables button in one form, it will disable button in all forms, when I try to do it with the class...

Comment: I edited the code and then edited the question.  I still have "TypeError: jQuery(...).val(...) is undefined" error though :((

Comment: @ArchieVigaca The function does it only for one particular ID.

Answer (score 1):

How about keep root simple? easier to read. and don't forget to change `#realname` to `.realname` (id to class), same as `button#submit`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var root = $('#conversation-<?php the_ID(); ?>');
  validate(root);
  root.find('.realname').change(function() {
    validate(root);
  });
});

function validate(root) {
  var found = root.find('.realname').val().length > 0;
  root.find('button.submit').prop('disabled', found);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response :)   I tried your code, now I get following error in console: "TypeError: root.find(...).val(...) is undefined"

Comment: console what's inside `root.find('.realname')` ? is it an form input element?

Comment: Yes, it is a text input element.